# How to place TueCrypt bootloader on CD?

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt, bootloader, compact-disc, optical-media

### Context

I want to encrypt my entire OS according to [this](http://lifehacker.com/5554136/hide-your-entire-operating-system-from-prying-eyes/) tutorial, which involves a decoy OS and a hidden one.

The problem I have with this setup is that the bootloader could be compromised with a password stealing one.

### Question

Does anyone of you know;

- How to remove any bootloader on the disk.
- How to place the TrueCrypt one on an optical disk, so that it is harder to compromise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't put the bootloader on optical media, instead I checksum the bootloader from optical media and chainload it to verify it is not tampered with.  Boot loader copy/removal can be done with dd from a linux live distro.

MagicISO is a gui that support copy/backup of boot sectors and burning to optical media, but I haven't tried it with the truecrypt loader

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the suggestion of MagicISO. But if I were to remove the boot sectors of the disk what should I use?

Comment: Repair to a standard 7 bootsector, install truecrypt bootsector, copy to iso/usb/sdcard, then remove...i think there's a trucrypt bootcd floating around

Comment: i couldn't find it atm, but i'm a linux freak so it isn't horribly pertinent to me.  I do manual mounting of crypted disks at offsets inside ext2 volumes to bypass the "identifiable header" problem

Comment: Well thank you very much for your troubles. I'll look into your suggestions.